# Should we Merge/Synonymise [button-remapping]/[remapping] -> [keyboard-layout]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request, tag-cleanup-request

[button-remapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/button-remapping) and [remapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remapping) are the same thing, and [keyboard-layout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-layout)'s Tag description says to use it for remapping keys.

I'm for merging both of the former into the latter. Does this seem sensible?

At the very least, [remapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remapping) should be merged with [button-remapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/button-remapping)

Comment: `keyboard-layout` yes, the `remapping` tags are useless. When they refer to mouse buttons, they should be tagged `mouse`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - there's also [keymap](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keymap)